# D3 rendering xAxis Months differently between FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I've created a simple bar chart where the yAxis is some arbitrary numbering and the xAxis is a timeScale from Jan-17 to Jan-18.  For some odd reason, Chrome is not displaying the first month (Jan-17).  For Firefox, I have the expected results.

I have tried using a combination for [`utcMonth` || `timeMonth`] and [`utcFormat` || `monthFormat`].  Each had varying results.

Am I miss understanding something between chrome and firefox?

**JS**

```
  x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date("2017-1-1"), new Date("2018-1-1")])
        .range([0, this.width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right - 40]);

  drawXAxis() {
   this.xAxis = this.g.append("g")
    .classed("bar-x-axis", true)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(this.x)
      .ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(1))
      .tickFormat(d3.utcFormat("%b-%y"))
  );
 }
```

**CSS**

```
.bar-x-axis text{
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.bar-x-axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

Attached are examples of both browser
Note: Chrome not displaying Jan17

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Kmo.png)
[ff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKswR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, thought it could have been a potential bug

fixed it by changing `new Date("2017-1-1")` to `new Date(2017, 0, 1)`